# Modifying Explorer View settings from Powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-explorer, windows-registry

Recently Windows changed the way Explorer sorts content by default in the Downloads folder. By default files are grouped by date downloaded, rather than displayed like any normal file other folders.

To change this back to normal: with the Downloads folder open, right click > group by > (none).

Is there anyway to configure this specific view change programmatically. Could modify a registry entry with the `Set-ItemProperty` cmdlet or run a .reg file but not able to find what path and key is needed. There's nothing that seems relevant at `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting GroupBy to (None), you should execute **Apply to Folders** to set that as the default for the **Downloads** *FolderType*.
[image]

Then run this **PowerShell** code to clear any Common Dialog views, as **Apply to Folders** only clears **Explorer** views.

```
$Bags = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
$DLID = '{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}'
(Get-ChildItem $bags -recurse | ? PSChildName -like $DLID ) | Remove-Item
gps explorer | spps
```

That should be sufficient if everything is working properly. An alternative way to modify the default are these registry entries that don't exist by default:

Per-User:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}]
"ColumnList"="prop:0(34)System.ItemNameDisplay;0System.DateModified;0System.ItemTypeText;0System.Size;1System.DateCreated;1System.Author;1System.Category;1System.Keywords;1System.Title"
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Name"="NoName"
"Order"=dword:00000000
"SortByList"="prop:System.ItemNameDisplay"
```

Machine-Wide:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
```